# Opencart custom page foreach not showing

Tags: foreach, opencart

Am creating a custom page using **Opencart**. Here am using `foreach` for displaying `customer` details.

But `customer` details not showing.

Following codes:

**.tpl**

```
    <?php foreach($dealerData as $invoice){ ?>
    <label> <b>Dealer Name:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $invoice['name']; ?></label><br>
    <label><b>Dealer TIN Number:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $invoice['tin_number'];?></label><br>
<?php } ?>
```

**Controller**

```
$query13 = $this->db->query("select concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as name, tin_number from ".DB_PREFIX."customer where customer_id='".$customer_id."'");
    $dataDelar = $query13->rows;
    foreach ($dataDelar as $dealer) {
        $data['dealerData'][] = array(
            'name' => $dealer['name'],
            'tin_number' => $dealer['tin_number']
            );
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the output of <?php print_r($invoiceData1); ?> in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you putting queries in your controller? You have models van database related functions. An foreach on the variable $invoiceData1 should work, you can see in the print_r that there is 1 array in the array. Did you put the print_r in your controller? So yes, look bellow that, maybe you are overriding $invoiceData1.

**EDIT**

You are not creating an empty array to put your values in:

```
$query13 = $this->db->query("select concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as name, tin_number from ".DB_PREFIX."customer where customer_id='".$customer_id."'");
$dataDelar = $query13->rows;
$data['dealerData'] = [];
foreach ($dataDelar as $dealer) {
  $data['dealerData'][] = array(
    'name' => $dealer['name'],
    'tin_number' => $dealer['tin_number']
  );
}
```

Comment: In `tpl` file i put `<?php var_dump($dealerData); ?>` it showing `NULL`. Where am make a mistake

Comment: But in controller file i put `var_dump($data['dealerData']);` it showing `array` values like **array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(11) "Test T" ["tin_number"]=> string(5) "55441" } }**